# How to display Google+ information on the right hand side by Google Search no matter which country I choose?

Tags: google-search

I have found a way to display Google+ information on the right hand side by Google Search. But I'm confused that when I switch search engine to different countries other than `.com`, like `.com.hk` or `.com.ca`, there is no Google+ information displayed.

Is it restricted by Google?

How to make Google+ information always displayed?

In addition, I found sometimes there's Wikipedia information displayed, not Google+.

How to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

Features like Google Universal Search or Knowledge Graph depend on your specific search, your search history (personalization) and are not offered with the same feature set or quality for every country. As long as you don't find a specific configuration option offered by Google you can't IMHO set or predict what will be displayed "right hand side".